# How do I configure dependency-check to handle TSX?

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

The NPM package dependency-check can be used to check that all dependencies are actually used in your project. It can handle non-javascript syntax by registering different `detective` extensions to handle various file extensions that will convert those files to an AST that can be processed by the plain `detective` instance.

When I run my dependency check script after adding a TSX file it exits with an error status and a very meager status message:

```
'>' expected.
```

I have configured it to work with JS, JSX, TS and TSX (see below), and it does work with three of the four. But after adding my first TSX file it failed as above.

The full config:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
EXE="$(npm bin)/dependency-check" 

"$EXE" package.json src/app.ts \
    --no-dev --unused \
    --extensions 'js,jsx:detective-es6' \
    --extensions 'ts,tsx:detective-typescript' \
    --ignore-module react-dom \
    --ignore-module mocha-teamcity-reporter \
    --ignore-module rimraf  \
    --ignore-module @types/react-dom \
    --ignore-module @types/react \
    --ignore-module @types/jss
```

This only started happening after adding my first TSX file, basically renaming an existing JSX file. I see that [`detective` needs a JSX flag passed as an option for this to work](https://github.com/pahen/detective-typescript/blob/master/test/test.js#L106), but I am not able to see how this is actually [passed through the layers](https://github.com/browserify/detective/blob/master/index.js).